# Clustering of Variables in python

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have hundreds of variables with binary values i.e., 1 & 0 and I want to see how these variables fall into different clusters? I don't see any python methods to apply. But I can see one in R: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0295.pdf

For example, I have data with variables(features) a1, a2, a3, a4,.......,a100. Each a's are binary variables. Instead of applying clustering on observations I want to apply clustering on a1,a2,...,a100 and want to see in which clusters a1 falls or a2 falls.

Does any one know similar package or methods in python? I tried to apply R interface in Anaconda so that I can use R methods but interface is not working.

Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)|

Answer (score 3):

First **transpose** your data matrix.

Then cluster features instead of instances!

Answer (score 0):

The package [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) has exactly what you are looking for.

It contains a lot of clustering algorithms like `K-means`,`Affinity propagation`, `Mean-shift`, `Spectral clustering`, `Ward hierarchical clustering`, `Agglomerative clustering`, `DBSCAN`, `Gaussian Mixtures` and more..

Comment: All those methods, in scikit-learn, are applied on observations not on variables. I have updated original question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Sanoj, is what you want to do not like PCA? (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

Comment: You can also look here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138325/clustering-a-correlation-matrix the answer provided code for covariance clustering.